# Google Sheets conditional formatting based off the cell address

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, match, string-formatting, conditional-formatting

I have a 10x10 grid, `B2:K11`, in google sheets. Column A and row 1 contain a randomized list from the numbers 0-9. `A12` and `A13` will have the coordinates of a cell inside the grid and I need that to be highlighted. Currently in my conditional formatting, I have `=ADDRESS(MATCH(A12, A2:A11, 0)+1,MATCH(A13, B1:K1,0)+1)=CELL("Address", B2)` (Applied to range `B2:K11`), but this will only highlight `B2` if the coordinates are the coordinates for B2...

I've tried changing the cell address in `=CELL("Address", B2)` to other cells, and that still will only highlight B2 if the given cell is a match. Example I change the conditional formatting to `=ADDRESS(MATCH(A12, A2:A11, 0)+1,MATCH(A13, B1:K1,0)+1)=CELL("Address", G6)` and set `A12` and `A13` to the header numbers that correspond the G6 and `B2` is the cell that gets highlighted instead of G6. (See image below for example)

[Example visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GL8Qn.png)

Obviously I'm doing something wrong but I'm not sure what it is..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=A1=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH($A$12, $A1, 0), MATCH($A$13, A$1, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! The only thing that needs to be changed is the range to `A1:K11` so that it highlights the correct box instead of offset diagonally 1.